# Is it possible that the fact the number of inflection points is zero changes in some different coordinate system?

Tags: geometry

Let $L$ be a line segment in the $3D$ Euclidean space. And Let $L_{xy}$ and $L_{xz}$ be the projections of $L$ onto the $XY$ and $XZ$ planes, respectively. Assume both of $L_{xy}$ and $L_{xz}$ have no inflection point. Does the assumption implies that: for any new coordinate system of the same type: both of the new $L_{xy}$ and $L_{xz}$ again have no inflection point?

Thank you in advance.

*As pointed out, I meant a piece of a curve by a line segment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you project a line segment onto a plane, it'll still be a line segment, hence have no inflections. (Except in the special case where the projection is a single point, i.e., a projection "along the line"; in that case there are no inflections, but the projection is a degenerate segment, i.e., a single point.)

If you mean "a piece of a curve", then it's quite possible for it to have inflection points in one set of projections and not in another.

As an example, consider 
$$
x(t) = t\\
y(t) = t^3 \\
z(t) = 0
$$
Clearly this has no inflection points.

But if you project into coordinates $u = x; v = y - x; w = z$, you get
$$
u(t) = t \\ 
v(t) = t^3 - t \\
z(t) = t
$$

and in the $uv$-plane, there's an inflection.